# Can't find the bug from my code of the 8-Queen algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Below is the my code for the eight queen problem. I believe it should work but the code doesn't give me right answer. I have spent hours to find the bug but I was not able to find the bug. I am dying to know where goes wrong. Please help!

```
public class EightQueen {
private boolean[][] queenOnSquare;
private boolean[] colEmpty;
private boolean[] upDiagEmpty;
private boolean[] downDiagEmpty;
private int numOfSol;
private int bordersize;


public EightQueen(int size){

//Initialize the object

    queenOnSquare=new boolean[size][size];
    colEmpty=new boolean[size];
    upDiagEmpty=new boolean[2*size-2];
    downDiagEmpty=new boolean[2*size-2];
    bordersize=size;
    numOfSol=0;
    for (int i=0;i<bordersize;i++){
        colEmpty[i]=true;
        upDiagEmpty[i]=true;
        downDiagEmpty[i]=true;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Create a new object of 8 queens

    EightQueen obj=new EightQueen(8);
    obj.solve();
    obj.printNumOfSol();

}

//This is just a wrapper method to study the recusion
public void solve(){
    findSolutions(0);
}

//This is the classic recursive backtracking
public void findSolutions(int row){
    if (row==bordersize){
        numOfSol++;
        printSol();
    }
    for (int col=0;col<bordersize;col++){
        if (isSafe(row,col)){
            placeQueen(row,col);
            findSolutions(row+1);
            removeQueen(row,col);
        }
    }

}
//Place the queen
public void placeQueen(int row, int col) {
    queenOnSquare[row][col] = true;
    colEmpty[col] = false;
    upDiagEmpty[row + col] = false;
    downDiagEmpty[(bordersize - 1) + row - col] = false;
}

//Remove the queen
public void removeQueen(int row, int col) {
    queenOnSquare[row][col] = false;
    colEmpty[col] = true;
    upDiagEmpty[row + col] = true;
    downDiagEmpty[(bordersize - 1) + row - col] = true;
}

//Judge if a new queen can be placed this spot
public boolean isSafe(int row, int col) {
    return (colEmpty[col]
    && upDiagEmpty[row + col]
    && downDiagEmpty[(bordersize - 1) + row - col]);
    }

//Print the solution
public void printSol(){
    System.out.println("Here is one solution:\n");
    for (int i=0;i<bordersize;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<bordersize;j++){
            if (queenOnSquare[i][j]) System.out.print("Q ");
            System.out.print(". ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

//Print the total number of solutions
public void printNumOfSol(){
    System.out.println("The number of solutions is: "+numOfSol);
}


}
```

Comment: Test each method separately, try using a debugger or try using print statements.

Comment: Hi. Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: You do not initialize the variables properly. I also suggest that you use printf debugging or the debugger.

Comment: What makes you think your code is wrong? how different yours from the perfect and *expected* programme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hej,

The comments above are right: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. It is better to narrow the problem down as much as possible and then ask more specifically.

Nonetheless: It is indeed only initialisation in the constructor and the bounds which are not right.

I think if you modify the constructor to

```
public EightQueen(int size) {
    //Initialize the object
    queenOnSquare=new boolean[size][size];
    colEmpty=new boolean[size];
    upDiagEmpty=new boolean[2*size-1];
    downDiagEmpty=new boolean[2*size-1];
    bordersize=size;
    numOfSol=0;
    for (int i=0;i<bordersize;i++){
        colEmpty[i]=true;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<2*bordersize-2;i++){
        upDiagEmpty[i]=true;
        downDiagEmpty[i]=true;
    }
}
```

things look better. Still, your programs says that there are 86 solutions, but there should be 92. :-)

Comment: The diag arrays need size `2*size-1` instead of `2*size-2` since they need to accomodate values `row+col` which may go up to 14 if `size` is 8.

Answer (score 0):

Per user3340630, upDiagEmpty and downDiagEmpty both have twice as many entries as you're initializing. It would probably make more sense to change them to "upDiagBlocked" and "downDiagBlocked", so you don't initialize (false is the default) and set them to true when they are blocked. But as it is, you just need to fully initialize those arrays to true.